# What is the global class name in this plugin php wordpress?

Tags: javascript, php, wordpress

I am trying to `remove_filter` from this plugin, as wordpress refrence

```
global $my_class;
remove_filter( 'the_content', array($my_class, 'class_filter_function') );
```

In this code, there is `'add_filter('bp_core_fetch_avatar', array($this, 'set_buddypress_avatar'), 10, 1);'`  that I would like to remove_filter, the big issue here, what is `$this`? I cannot global `$this`, so what is the `$my_class` in the following code?

I had tried `global $BuddyPress_First_Letter_Avatar` and `global BuddyPress_First_Letter_Avata`, 
it gave me error.

```html
<?php
class BuddyPress_First_Letter_Avatar {

 // Setup (these values always stay the same):
 const BPFLA_IMAGES_PATH = 'images'; // avatars root directory
 const BPFLA_GRAVATAR_URL = 'https://secure.gravatar.com/avatar/';    // default url for gravatar - we're using HTTPS to avoid annoying warnings

 // Default configuration (this is the default configuration only for the first plugin usage):
 const BPFLA_USE_PROFILE_AVATAR = TRUE;  // TRUE: if user has his profile avatar, use it; FALSE: use custom avatars or Gravatars
 const BPFLA_USE_GRAVATAR = TRUE;  // TRUE: if user has Gravatar, use it; FALSE: use custom avatars or user's profile avatar
 const BPFLA_AVATAR_SET = 'default'; // directory where avatars are stored
 const BPFLA_LETTER_INDEX = 0;  // 0: first letter; 1: second letter; -1: last letter, etc.
 const BPFLA_IMAGES_FORMAT = 'png';   // file format of the avatars
 const BPFLA_ROUND_AVATARS = FALSE;     // TRUE: use rounded avatars; FALSE: dont use round avatars
 const BPFLA_IMAGE_UNKNOWN = 'mystery';    // file name (without extension) of the avatar used for users with usernames beginning
          // with symbol other than one from a-z range
 // variables duplicating const values (will be changed in constructor after reading config from DB):
 private $use_profile_avatar = self::BPFLA_USE_PROFILE_AVATAR;
 private $use_gravatar = self::BPFLA_USE_GRAVATAR;
 private $avatar_set = self::BPFLA_AVATAR_SET;
 private $letter_index = self::BPFLA_LETTER_INDEX;
 private $images_format = self::BPFLA_IMAGES_FORMAT;
 private $round_avatars = self::BPFLA_ROUND_AVATARS;
 private $image_unknown = self::BPFLA_IMAGE_UNKNOWN;



 public function __construct(){

  // add Settings link to plugins page:
  add_filter('plugin_action_links_' . plugin_basename(__FILE__), array($this, 'bpfla_add_settings_link'));

  // add stylesheets/scripts:
  add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts', array($this, 'bpfla_add_scripts'));

  // add filter to get_avatar:
  add_filter('get_avatar', array($this, 'set_comment_avatar'), 10, 5); // this will only be used for anonymous WordPress comments

  // add filter to bp_core_fetch_avatar:
  add_filter('bp_core_fetch_avatar', array($this, 'set_buddypress_avatar'), 10, 1);

  // get plugin configuration from database:
  $options = get_option('bpfla_settings');
  if (empty($options)){
   // no records in DB, use default (const) values to save plugin config:
   $settings = array(
    'bpfla_use_profile_avatar' => self::BPFLA_USE_PROFILE_AVATAR,
    'bpfla_use_gravatar' => self::BPFLA_USE_GRAVATAR,
    'bpfla_avatar_set' => self::BPFLA_AVATAR_SET,
    'bpfla_letter_index' => self::BPFLA_LETTER_INDEX,
    'bpfla_file_format' => self::BPFLA_IMAGES_FORMAT,
    'bpfla_round_avatars' => self::BPFLA_ROUND_AVATARS,
    'bpfla_unknown_image' => self::BPFLA_IMAGE_UNKNOWN
   );
   add_option('bpfla_settings', $settings);
  } else {
   // there are records in DB for our plugin, let's assign them to our variables:
   $this->use_profile_avatar = $options['bpfla_use_profile_avatar'];
   $this->use_gravatar = $options['bpfla_use_gravatar'];
   $this->avatar_set = $options['bpfla_avatar_set'];
   $this->letter_index = $options['bpfla_letter_index'];
   $this->images_format = $options['bpfla_file_format'];
   $this->round_avatars = $options['bpfla_round_avatars'];
   $this->image_unknown = $options['bpfla_unknown_image'];
  }

 }


?>public function set_buddypress_avatar($html_data = ''){

  $html_doc = new DOMDocument();
  $html_doc->loadHTML($html_data);
  $image = $html_doc->getElementsByTagName('img');
  foreach($image as $data) {
   $original_image = $data->getAttribute('src');
   $size = $data->getAttribute('width');
   $alt = $data->getAttribute('alt');
      
   if (stripos($alt, 'Profile picture of ') === 0){ // if our alt attribute has "profile picture of" in the beginning...
    $name = str_replace('Profile picture of ', '', $alt);
      
   } else if (stripos($alt, 'Profile photo of ') === 0){ // or profile photo of...
    $name = str_replace('Profile photo of ', '', $alt);
       
   } else { // if there is some problem - just assign alt to name
    $name = $alt;
       
   }
  }

  // something went wrong, just return what came in function argument:
  if (empty($original_image) || empty($size) || empty($name) || empty($alt)){
   return $html_data;
  }

  // if there is no gravatar URL it means that user has set his own profila avatar,
  // so we're gonna see if we should be using it;
  // if we should, just return the input data and leave the avatar as it was:
  if ($this->use_profile_avatar == TRUE){
   if (stripos($original_image, 'gravatar.com/avatar') === FALSE){
    return $html_data;
   }
  }

  // check whether Gravatar should be used at all:
  if ($this->use_gravatar == TRUE){
   // gravatar used as default option, now check whether user's gravatar is set:
   if ($this->gravatar_exists_uri($original_image)){
    // gravatar is set, return input data (nothing changes):
    return $html_data;
   } else {
    // gravatar is not set, proceed to choose custom avatar:
    $avatar_output = $this->choose_custom_avatar($name, $size, $alt,$gender);
   }
  } else {
   // gravatar is not used as default option, only custom avatars will be used; proceed to choose custom avatar:
   $avatar_output = $this->choose_custom_avatar($name, $size, $alt,$gender);
  }

  return $avatar_output;

 }
```

Comment: « I am trying to `remove_filter` from this plugin ». What **exactly** are you trying to achieve?

Comment: trying to remove this add_filter('bp_core_fetch_avatar', array($this, 'set_buddypress_avatar'), 10, 1); in this plugin

Comment: What happens if you do?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried something like this

```
remove_filter( 'the_content', array('BuddyPress_First_Letter_Avatar ', 'class_filter_function') );
```